# Call a secured (pfx) .NET webservice from Java (Alfresco)

Tags: java, asp.net, web-services, alfresco, pfx

I'm sorry I'm new in Web Service specification and more specially with secured web service.

I try to access a secured web service given by a .net application from an Alfreco web script. I've got .pfx file and .cer file and I already have method to access to a similar unsecured web service.

So I just have to add certificate but after a lot of research I'm a little bit lost and I don't know where begin.

Can somebody help me?

Cdt